# Xcode/Objective-C - pass data through prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a UIViewController with a MapView.
My prepareForSegue Method looks like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mapDetailPage"]) {
        vumLocationViewController *vvc = segue.destinationViewController;

    vvc.profilId = [[self.parser.locationsArray objectAtIndex:1] profilId];
    vvc.profilType = [[self.parser.locationsArray objectAtIndex:1] profilType];
    vvc.displayName = [[self.parser.locationsArray objectAtIndex:1] displayName];

    return;
    }
}
```

Now the Problem is I need an IndexPath(or Sth. like that) to get the Data from the right index and not from the index 1.

Here are the other maybe important lines:

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    if ((oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude) || (oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude))
    {

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {
            .latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
            .longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude};

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center = coord;

        MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta = 0.1, .longitudeDelta = 0.1};
        region.span = span;

        for(int i = 0; i < [self.parser.locationsArray count]; i++)
        {
            double latitude = [[[self.parser.locationsArray objectAtIndex:i] latitude] doubleValue];
            double longitude = [[[self.parser.locationsArray objectAtIndex:i] longitude] doubleValue];
            coord.latitude = latitude;
            coord.longitude = longitude;


            NSString *openingTimes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@", [[self.parser.locationsArray objectAtIndex:i] street] ,[[self.parser.locationsArray objectAtIndex:i] opening1], [[self.parser.locationsArray objectAtIndex:i] opening2]];


            PlaceMark *placeMark = [[PlaceMark alloc]
                                    initWithCoordinate:coord
                                    andMarkTitle: [[self.parser.locationsArray objectAtIndex:i] displayName]
                                    andMarkSubTitle:openingTimes
                                    andMarkProfilType:[[self.parser.locationsArray objectAtIndex:i] profilType]];
            [myMapView addAnnotation:placeMark];
            placeMark = nil;
        }

    }
}

    //view For Annotation
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *identifier = @"myLocation";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[PlaceMark class]])
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil)
        {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                              initWithAnnotation:annotation
                              reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        }
        else
        {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIImageView *calloutImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gastronomie.png"]];
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = calloutImage;
        annotationView.highlighted = YES;

        /*if([[[self.parser.locationsArray objectAtIndex: annotation] category] isEqualToString:@"Gastronomie"])
        {
            NSLog(@"Ist Gastronomie");
            annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        }*/

        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

        // Create a UIButton object to add on the
        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [annotationView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];

        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}


    //calloutAccessoryControlTapped
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    if ([(UIButton*)control buttonType] == UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure)
    {
        if (![view.annotation isKindOfClass:[PlaceMark class]])
            return;

        // use the annotation view as the sender
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mapDetailPage" sender: view];

        // Do your thing when the detailDisclosureButton is touched

        UIViewController *vumLocationViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vumLocationViewController animated:YES];

    }
}
```

So how do I get this Array Index in the prepareForSegue method?

Comment: You will get it from the sender object. It's the object that invoke the segue and is passed in prepareForSegue. Depending on the object, you can cast it into your desired object and grab its index from your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass everything you need via `sender` parameter.
Look, in your current implementation you are passing `MKAnnotationView` instance in `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mapDetailPage" sender: view];`. So, in your `-(void)prepareForSegue:sender:`. You can get an annotation - `PlaceMark *annotation = (PlaceMark*)[(MKAnnotationView*)sender annotation];`
From that annotation you can get anything you set to it, like profilType, latitude etc. Disclosing this to full code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mapDetailPage"]) {
        vumLocationViewController *vvc = segue.destinationViewController;

    PlaceMark *annotation = (PlaceMark*)[(MKAnnotationView*)sender annotation];
    vvc.profilId = [annotation profilId];
    vvc.profilType = [annotation profilType];
    vvc.displayName = [annotation displayName];
    }
}
```